# Subtotal VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have an excel spreadsheet like the one below (I made all confidential info white font so ignore the blank space)

[image]

The total column is in column d or the 4th column. What I need to do is subtotal the values in column d up until it gets to row that says "...-TOTAL". The issue I'm having is that after the row with "...-TOTAL" there are more rows that also need to be subtotaled up to "...-TOTAL" with "..." being the client's name. I've tried the code below but I think it's stuck in an infinite loop because instead of the script running 5 minutes and ending, it isn't ending at all. If you need more information please let me know. Thank you!

```
Do Until InStr(objExcel.Cells(c,2).Value, "TOTAL")
total = total + objExcel.Cells(e,4).Value
if InStr(objExcel.Cells(c,2).Value, "TOTAL") then 
    objExcel.Cells(c,4).Value = total
    total = 0
end if
Loop
```

Comment: There is a lot wrong here. `Cells()` takes two arguments. 1) The row 2) The Column number. This should check `InStr(objExcel.Cells(2, 3).Value, "TOTAL")` But even that does make sense as we don't want to check the cell `C2` over and over again looking for "Total". It's value never changes. A `For Each` loop would be much better here.

Comment: @user648026 Please don't edit the picture back to a link. It is not helpful.

Comment: @JNevill at the beginning of my code I have c = 1, does Do Until not increment c each time it loops through until 'TOTAL' is found in column 2?

Comment: Share all relevant code, since C is in the above code, it falls in scope. I dont see where C is being incremented (Ex: For C = 1 to ?)

Comment: It won't increment it unless you increment it in the loop like `c=c+1`. Only a `For` loop will autoincrement like: `For c=1 to 5000`, but obviously that won't work well here since you don't know your ending valu.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in my comment you should use a `For Each` loop here so you can check the value of "Total" in each Row's Column 2 (B). Something like:

```
'Loop through each cell in column B
For Each rngCell in Range("B:B").Cells
    'Check to see if it contains "TOTAL" as part of it's value
    If Instr(rngCell.value, "TOTAL") Then
        'Set the value of the cell 2 columns over (Column D) and exit loop
        rngCell.Offset(,2).value = total
        Exit For
    End If
    'Collect and increment the total
    total = total + rngCell.Offset(,2).value
Next
```

Comment: Oh okay, I'm going to try this solution as the logic makes much more sense than do until. Thank you!

Comment: The only ugly thing here is that if "TOTAL" isn't found in column B then you will iterate through 1M cells before exiting. You may want to toss an extra line at the top to kill it off at some high range like `If rngCell.Row() = 50000 Then Exit For` Just in case.

Comment: ... or do a find/match/countif check before entering the loop.